# populate model with user model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm using an oauth strategy which populates the in build user model from dotnet. Now i want to populate my own model with this user model and then also fetch more info from the API provided by the third party service from which i use the oauth. Now i am slighty confused how to populate my own model with the user. How should i do this. Besided is use the MVC achitecture.

controller

```
namespace AspNetCoreGitHubAuth.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Welcome()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
            return View();
        }
```

Welcome.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "test welcome";
}
// i want to display the user info on this page
<h2>test welcome</h2>
```

model

```
namespace AspNetCoreGitHubAuth.Models
{
    public class Github
    {
        public class IndexModel
        {
            public string GitHubAvatar { get; set; }

            public string GitHubLogin { get; set; }

            public string GitHubName { get; set; }

            public string GitHubUrl { get; set; }

            public IReadOnlyList<Repository> Repositories { get; set; }

            //public async Task OnGetAsync()
            //{
                /*if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    GitHubName = User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
                    GitHubLogin = User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "urn:github:login")?.Value;
                    GitHubUrl = User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "urn:github:url")?.Value;
                    GitHubAvatar = User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "urn:github:avatar")?.Value;

                    string accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

                    var github = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("AspNetCoreGitHubAuth"), new InMemoryCredentialStore(new Credentials(accessToken)));
                    Repositories = await github.Repository.GetAllForCurrent();

                }*/
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will help you: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/oauth-2-0-with-github-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Can you please share your services method from startup.cs?

Comment: The link you provided uses razorpages. This is slightly different from a view page as the model in a razor page can extend the pageModel class which let u use onGetAsync that excecutes the fetch and such

Comment: My statup.cs is an exact copy of the startup.cs file in the link you provided :)

Comment: Ok, What I would suggest is try to use ILogger and log that persisted user received from GitHub endpoint before you try and use any of its values. This is just to see if it infact return all those values.